# Oracle data integrator

Tags: oracle

I have created a package which consist of several mappings. when I run the package, everything works fine, however, when I generate a scenario, the scenario  runs thru the mappings without actually doing any of them. When I look at the execution steps, it seems the context is set to "undefined" for each step. This happens from time to time.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the package?  From SQL Plus, SQL Developer, a scheduled job?  Explain what you mean by mappings and scenarios.  How do you generate a scenario?  Are they set of parameters?

Comment: The scenario is generated in ODI and it's also run in ODI studio. Also there are no parameters.